# Feeding step number into `sess.run`

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, is it possible to use the step number (e.g. by providing it, e.g. through `feed_dict`) inside the part of the program that is executed with `sess.run()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To create the global step you can either:

- use a builtin optimizer, like Adam (global step will be a dependence of the train op)
- in tf 0.11 use [tf.contrib.framework.create_global_step](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.framework.html#create_global_step), which creates a tf variable:

  ```
  step = tf.contrib.framework.create_global_step()
  ```
- in tf 0.12 use [tf.train.global_step](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/training_utilities#global_step):

  ```
  global_step_tensor = tf.Variable(10, trainable=False, name='global_step')
  tf.train.global_step(sess, global_step_tensor)
  ```

To retrieve the global step you can use [tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.framework.html#get_global_step) (tf 0.11) or [tf.train.get_global_step](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#get_global_step) (tf 0.12). They return a variable, which you can freely access/assign:

```
sess.run(tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step())
Out: 0

step_place = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
ass_op = tf.assign(tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(), step_place)
sess.run(ass_op, feed_dict={step_place: 42})
Out: 42
sess.run(tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step())
Out: 42
```

Comment: Hmm.. But `ass_op` stil returns TF variable (if I make `print(ass_op`), not the value 42.

Comment: Shouldn't I create anywhere a variable `global_step=tf.Variable(0, name="global_step")`?

Comment: @cerebrou Sorry I wasn't clear. I made more explanation. As to your questions: `create_global_step()` in tf 0.11 creates a variable for you; in tf 0.12 you need to do it by yourself.
`get_global_step()`, as well as `tf.assign` on it, returns a tf variable. To get the value of the variable you need to evaluate it using `sess.run` (or `.eval()`).